# Is it possible to define an attribute as both a string or a knownstring?

Tags: c#, xsd

E.g. I would like to have several reserved strings, that have custom behavior in my program. I would like to communicate to people consuming the Schema, which values will have pre-programmed behavior.

Say that "a" "b" "c" "d" are reserved.

if someone specifies "customOperation1" then it would get treated in code as a custom value.

Where as if someone uses "a" then the pre programmed behavior for "a" would be invoked.

Currently I just have it as a string field, but is there a way to convey a 'string with extra meaning and keywords' to XML?

e.g.

```
  <xs:simpleType name="operation" final="restriction">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="a"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="b"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Will allow me to specify an enum called operation, with values "a" and "b"

How can I do the same thing, but also allowing custom entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a union of an enumeration and a string, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:simpleType name="SpecialOp" final="restriction">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="a"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="b"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="CustomOp">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="Operation">
    <xs:union memberTypes="SpecialOp CustomOp"/>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="op" type="Operation"/>

</xs:schema>
```

This will accept any string value for `op`, but still convey the meaning of the special values.